# How to order C structure/function declarations which use each other?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, symbols

I am trying to create a structure by the name **"IExampleVtbl"** that will hold a pointer to my functions **(SetStringPtr,GetStringPtr)** and will be a part of another structure **"IExample"**.

But I want to pass the other structure **"IExample"** as parameter to the functions **(SetStringPtr,GetStringPtr)**.

This is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr *SetString;
    GetStringPtr *GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

typedef struct {
    IExampleVtbl *lpVtbl;
    DWORD   count;
    char    buffer[80];
} IExample;

typedef long SetStringPtr(IExample *, char *);
typedef long GetStringPtr(IExample *, char *, long);

long SetString(IExample *this, char * str)
{
    ...

    return(0);
}

long GetString(IExample *this, char *buffer, long length)
{
    ...

    return(0);
}
```

As you can see the first structure need to know about the functions,
the functions need to know about the second structure which need to know about the first structure.

How I can solved that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve the problems by putting things in the following order

- typedefs for the structures
- typedefs for the function pointers
- structure definitions
- function definitions

To make that work, you'll need to define the structures with tags:

```
typedef struct IExampleVtblTag IExampleVtbl;
typedef struct IExampleTag IExample;
typedef long SetStringPtr(IExample *, char *);
typedef long GetStringPtr(IExample *, char *, long);

struct IExampleVtblTag {
    SetStringPtr *SetString;
    GetStringPtr *GetString;
};

struct IExampleTag {
    IExampleVtbl *lpVtbl;
    DWORD   count;
    char    buffer[80];
};

long SetString(IExample *this, char * str)
{
    return(0);
}

long GetString(IExample *this, char *buffer, long length)
{
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You combine a *forward declaration* with the type-alias definition:

```
// Forward declaration of the structure IExample
// And at the same time definition of the type-alias IExample
typedef struct IExample IExample;

typedef long SetStringPtr(IExample *, char *);
typedef long GetStringPtr(IExample *, char *, long);

// Now the definition of the structures
typedef struct { ... } IExampleVtbl;

// Because the previous type-alias definition, we need to specify a structure tag
struct IExample { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

typedef for the struct to be typedef'd can precede the definition of struct, so a bit of re-arrangement should make things work here

```
typedef struct IExample IExample;

typedef long SetStringPtr(IExample *, char *);
typedef long GetStringPtr(IExample *, char *, long);

typedef struct {
    SetStringPtr *SetString;
    GetStringPtr *GetString;
} IExampleVtbl;

struct IExample {
    IExampleVtbl *lpVtbl;
    long   count;
    char    buffer[80];
};
```

Comment: Symbols with leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter is reserved for the "implementation" (compiler and standard library) in all scopes. And since structure tags live in a separate namespace, they can have the same name as other symbols (like the type-alias) so the underscore isn't needed.

Comment: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)